# Persist entity with Map<String, List<String>> field in JPA

Tags: java, jpa

For a field in Process class as Map<String, List> messages, I have desinged the entities as below

```
    @Entity(name = "Process")
    @Table(name = "Process")
    public class Process{

    private String id;

    private String processKey;

    @OneToMany(targetEntity=Messages.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "processId")
    @MapKey(name = "messageKey")
    public Map<String, Messages> messagesMap = new HashMap<>(); 

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "system-uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "system-uuid", strategy = "xxx.hibernate.EntityIdGenerator")
    @Override
    public String getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getProcessKey() {
        return processKey;
    }

    public void setProcessKey(String processKey) {
        this.processKey = processKey;
    }

    public void setMessagesMap(Map<String, Messages> messagesMap) {
        this.messagesMap = messagesMap;
    }

    public void putMessages(String key, String value) {
        if(messagesMap.containsKey(key)) {
            messagesMap.get(key).add(value);
        } else {
            Messages messages = new Messages();
            messages.messageKey = key;
            messages.messages = value;
            messagesMap.put(key, messages);
        }
    } 

   // no getter for messages
 }
```

And the Messges class

```
@Entity(name = "Messages")
@Table(name = "Messages")
public class Messages {
    
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "messageKey")
    public  String messageKey;

    @Column(name = "message")
    public  String message;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "system-uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "system-uuid", strategy = "xxx.hibernate.EntityIdGenerator")
    @Override
    public String getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "messageKey", referencedColumnName = "messageKey")
    public List<Messages> values = new ArrayList<>();

    public void add(String messages) {
        Messages messages = new Messages();
        messages.messageKey = messageKey;
        messages.messages = messages;
        values.add(messages);
    }

    public String getMessageKey() {
        return messageKey;
    }

    public void setMessageKey(String messageKey) {
        this.messageKey = messageKey;
    }

    public String getMessages() {
        return messages;
    }

    public void setMessages(String messages) {
        this.messages = messages;
    }

    public void setValues(List<Messages> values) {
        this.values = values;
    }
}
```

In the service

```
Process process = new Process();
process.setProcessKey...
process.putMessages....
em.persist(process);
```

This results in a entry in Process table, but no inserts in Message table. No exception is thrown either. I have `<property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>` and I can see no Insert query is generated for Message table.

- Do I need to persist Message object seperately ?
- Is there any way to do it via persisting Process object only ?

Please also let me know if my mapping is incorrect.

Comment: You have to mappings for processId once as JoinColumn other on Message entity as column

Comment: @SimonMartinelli : Sorry, I didn't get it. How it should be otherwise ?

Comment: Remove processId from Message and try again

Comment: I can't remove `processId `, that is my reference to the Process table.

Comment: No the reference is  @JoinColumn(name = "processId") on the messageMap

Comment: But in the Message table I need a `processId` column. And If I remove the field, how hibernate will know what column I am refering to by `@JoinColumn(name = "processId")` ?

Comment: Exactly through this JoinColumn annotation :-)

Comment: Same result. No inserts in Messages table.

Comment: One problem is that you have the Messages.message column mapped 3 different ways. the first is as a mapKey set through the the processes.messageMap mapping, another is through the Messages.message basic mapping, with the third being through  Messages.values OneToMany. Since you are mapping Messages->Messages using this column, it doesn't make sense to me that messages is also a container class for other messages; the system will get confused with an infinite graph, as the parent is also the child in its own values oneToMany.